# Manga about multiple people who get betrayed and join together

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manga that I lost like a year or two ago.

The main plot was that there different people at a table drinking together while in thought on how each of them were betrayed by people and at the same moment they shout some where along the lines of "people are the worst" I think. I know that there's one guy, a girl, and a priest who started drinking for his own reasons and a few more people but during one of the chapters they beat a boss and find a talking sword. Because they don't want trouble they make a fake sword and keep the talking sword. Also, at the beginning when they meet each other, they all get drunk together and fall asleep in a room, all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[The Adventurers That Don't Believe in Humanity Will Save the World](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ningen-fushin-no-boukensha-tachi-ga-sekai-wo-sukuu-you-desu)*, aka *Ningen Fushin no Boukensha-tachi ga Sekai wo Sukuu You desu*.

> On that day, an adventurer with a wealth of experience, Nick was expelled from the party by the leader whom he looked up to as a father. Despite his constant support for his slovenly party members, be it financially or in teaching them, he was framed for embezzlement and expelled. Dumped by his girlfriend as well, Nick was thoroughly depressed and **went to a bar to drink away his sorrows when he found companions in a former noble lady, an excommunicated priest, and a female dragonoid warrior**. They were similarly adventurers who had been betrayed and could no longer trust others! Precisely because they all knew the pain of being betrayed, they decided to team up as a party to earn a living. “How about we call ourselves the ‘Survivors’?”

Synopsis is a solid match for the question. The ["people are the worst"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGAyE.jpg) scene is in the opening. The talking sword is the "sword of bonds" and appears in the chapter with the same name.

[image: Creepy talking sword]